# Installing XP, no USB boot, no network driver

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp, installation

Am trying to install Win XP on an Aopen Digital Engine, using PXE (Serva). There is no option to boot from USB. Have already tried to move the HD to another machine, but that did not work (after moving it back, Windows seemed ok, spent a while mulling it over, and reached the conclusion that it could not start.)

When booting XP over PXE, it says that it cannot find network drivers. I have the drivers in a zip file.

The question is: how do I combine drivers and Windows files before starting the installation process. It is a 32 bit version and I have no 32 bit machine (but want to run old software later). I have copied the files from the ISO to my HD (on a laptop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows installer can't load extra drivers, with the exception of storage drivers.

What you have to do is modify the installation media to include these drivers. You can do this with [nLite](https://www.nliteos.com/) which is free and awesome. It's pretty straightforward to use:

- Select directory to operate on (or optical disk to copy installer files from)
- Choose driver integration (and creating an ISO if you need it)
- Choose drivers to integrate
- (optionally) Make an ISO

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer `Windows installer can't load extra drivers` is not correct; When PXE installing a RIS OS like XP the installer "asks" for the correct NIC driver and the PXE server must provide it.

Serva explains how to add OEM drivers to PXE install Windows XP here:

[https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1_2_RIS.html#troubleshooting](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/WindowsPXE1_2_RIS.html#troubleshooting)

*5.3- Troubleshooting Network driver issues.*

it basically consist of copying the XP NIC driver components NetDriverX.inf, NetDriverY.sys, and NetDriverY.cat (if available) under:

`C:\SERVA_REPO\WIA_RIS\Win_XP\$OEM$\$1\Drivers\NIC\`

and reboot Serva

Comment: The accepted answer explains how to add the drivers to the installation media (ie iso file). I think I tried something like what you say but it did not work (maybe there were no inf/cat files, or something like that).

Comment: The OP says `When booting XP over PXE...` and you are talking conventional install. In a PXE install (as I said before) the installer asks for the network driver in a BINL network transaction (similar to DHCP) and the Server must provide it. This happens at "install time"

Comment: Well, Serva is the PXE server, then sure it must have the required driver loaded in its database before it's requested by a client install. You must provide the driver components, sometimes this require extracting them from a install blob or other running PC

Comment: Loading an "extra" or "OEM" diver in Serva's database is making available for PXE installation NIC drivers not originally included in the corresponding distribution ISO